# How can I read this JSON file into python pandas as a DataFrame. The main focus is on "Names" variable. This is the sample similar to my data

Tags: python, json, pandas

How can I read this JSON file into python pandas as a Data Frame. The main focus is on "Names" variable. I have created this sample JSON. I am trying to parse this JSON. All the keys need to be converted as a column name and values as data. I am struggling in doing this as the feature "Names" has multiple nested JSON objects. Thanks in Advance.

```
{
        "entityType": "Entity",
        "isreal": true,
        "ispresent": false,
        "isExtract": false,
        "executionId": "3d0hy143-f58e-4fe7-8d83-3e1a011d448c",
        "controlNumber": "on1072226092",
        "field979": [
            "$xNEW",
            "$520200877062234"
        ],
        "TagNumbers": [
            "9781355445025",
            "1375323029"
        ],
        "flrs": [],
        "atsNumbers960": [
            "moo3452842",
            "moo3452842",
            "moo3452842",
            "moo3452842",
            "moo3452842"
        ],
        "Names": [
            {
                "tag": "King",
                "data": "03190cam a2200589Ii 4500"
            },
            {
                "type": "controller",
                "tag": "007",
                "data": "on1071233092",
                "ind1": " ",
                "ind2": " "
            },
            {
                "type": "controlfield",
                "tag": "777",
                "data": "181126s2019    nyuab    6    000 1 eng d",
                "ind1": " ",
                "ind2": " "
            },
            {
                "tag": "000",
                "ind1": " ",
                "ind2": " ",
                "subfields": [
                    {
                        "code": "a",
                        "data": "NEW"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "b",
                        "data": "spa"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "c",
                        "data": "new"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "d",
                        "data": "VP@"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "d",
                        "data": "OCLCF"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tag": "020",
                "ind1": " ",
                "ind2": " ",
                "subNames": [
                    {
                        "code": "a",
                        "data": "9733302915025"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tag": "020",
                "ind1": " ",
                "ind2": " ",
                "subfields": [
                    {
                        "code": "a",
                        "data": "1302915029"
                    }
                ]
            }
    }
```

Comment: How should the DF look like?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking and the dataframe should like this                                                      entityType isreal ispresent isExtract executionId controlNumber field979 TagNumbers flrs atsNumbers960 Names tag data type ind1 ind2 subfields code data
Even I don't have complete idea of how and what to set in the DataFrame but this is something I have in my mind.